# SQL join filling null columns

Tags: sql, join, merge, lookup

I have two tables where I need to do a **FULL JOIN.** Table2 has many missing values that can be found in table1.

I need to **combine** (if column1, 2 and 3 are the same) and **append** the information from table2 filling the null values from table1.

TABLE1

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | measure1 | measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | DAY1 | ***50*** | null |
| A | B | DAY2 | 10 | null |

TABLE 2

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | measure1 | measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | DAY1 | null | ***100*** |
| A | null | DAY3 | null | 300 |

DESIRED RESULT

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | measure1 | measure2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | DAY1 | ***50*** | ***100*** |
| A | B | DAY2 | 10 | null |
| A | **B** | DAY3 | null | 300 |

In this case, I combined first rows from table1 and table2. For second row in table2 we lookup the value of column2 from table1.1.

Comment: There is no way to know with what value to replace the `NULL` in the second table.

Comment: it is based on column1 matches

Comment: 2nd row from table2 has no matched column 1, 2, 3 in table1 because column2 is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` here:

```
select 
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id,
    coalesce(t1.c1, t2.c1) c1,
    coalesce(t1.c2, t2.c2) c2
from t1
full outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

[SQLize fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/edbd7d6c8927a615a71f909a2f87f89a/)

Comment: The expected output has _five_ columns while your query has only _three_.  How can this answer be correct?

Comment: thanks, that would not fill the null value from table2 right?

Comment: The `coalesce` function returns firs not null value, so nut null values from t1 will be resent prior t2 values

Comment: wow thank you very much. however, column1 could also have another value, we need to lookup for the match in column1. any idea how to solve that